# Mysql installer is showing "Mysql connector is already installed" for the removed one

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I am installing

```
mysql dot net connnector 6.9.9
```

in my `windows 8` by using mysql installer.But it is showing `Connector 6.9.4` is already present in the system, so it stops installation after 50%.When I tried to remove or upgrade it stops after 50%.So i could not install or remove mysql connector.I could not find where because I removed everywhere in my system including control panel and even regedit also.But it is not removing.How do i remove old version of mysql connector completely